# Safehouse || Is SafeHouse is BU level or Enterprice level || SFMC SFTP Achitecture

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does any one know,

1. Is Safe House is BU level? or Enterprise level?
2. Can a file in Child BU1 can be picked up by Child BU2?
3. Which of the below 2 architectures is correct?

| Architecture-1 | Architecture-2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have their own safehouse, they are not shared across the tenant

Comment: Thanks @EasyE this was the answer I was looking into, as I could not find over any docs. Any supporting link/article from Salesforce on this?